# Update to VBA7 causes Username and Password Prompt Error

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code which works in Excel 2010(prompts users to enter username and password upon opening the workbook as well as masking the password with "*").  My Excel was updated to Excel 2013 and now the code does not work.  After I am prompted for my Username, it errors for "type mismatch" and when I look in the VBA editor the following is highlighted

```
Public Function InputBoxDK(Prompt, Optional Title, Optional Default, Optional XPos, _
Optional YPos, Optional HelpFile, Optional Context) As String
```

Along with `AddressOf NewProc`

The code below is the entire sequence for obtaining the username and password when opening the workbook.

```
#If VBA7 Then
Private Declare PtrSafe Function CallNextHookEx Lib "user32" (ByVal hHook As Long, _
ByVal ncode As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, lParam As Any) As Long
#Else
Private Declare Function CallNextHookEx Lib "user32" (ByVal hHook As Long, _
ByVal ncode As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, lParam As Any) As Long
#End If

#If VBA7 Then
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetModuleHandle Lib "kernel32" Alias _
"GetModuleHandleA" (ByVal lpModuleName As String) As Long
#Else
Private Declare Function GetModuleHandle Lib "kernel32" Alias _
"GetModuleHandleA" (ByVal lpModuleName As String) As Long
#End If

#If VBA7 Then
Private Declare PtrSafe Function SetWindowsHookEx Lib "user32" Alias "SetWindowsHookExA" _
(ByVal idHook As Long, ByVal lpfn As Long, ByVal hmod As Long, _
ByVal dwThreadId As Long) As Long
#Else
Private Declare Function SetWindowsHookEx Lib "user32" Alias "SetWindowsHookExA" _
(ByVal idHook As Long, ByVal lpfn As Long, ByVal hmod As Long, _
ByVal dwThreadId As Long) As Long
#End If

#If VBA7 Then
Private Declare PtrSafe Function UnhookWindowsHookEx Lib "user32" (ByVal hHook As Long) As Long
#Else
Private Declare Function UnhookWindowsHookEx Lib "user32" (ByVal hHook As Long) As Long
#End If

#If VBA7 Then
Private Declare PtrSafe Function SendDlgItemMessage Lib "user32" Alias "SendDlgItemMessageA" _
(ByVal hDlg As Long, ByVal nIDDlgItem As Long, ByVal wMsg As Long, _
ByVal wParam As Long, ByVal lParam As Long) As Long
#Else
Private Declare Function SendDlgItemMessage Lib "user32" Alias "SendDlgItemMessageA" _
(ByVal hDlg As Long, ByVal nIDDlgItem As Long, ByVal wMsg As Long, _
ByVal wParam As Long, ByVal lParam As Long) As Long
#End If

#If VBA7 Then
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetClassName Lib "user32" Alias "GetClassNameA" _
(ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal nMaxCount As Long) As Long
#Else
Private Declare Function GetClassName Lib "user32" Alias "GetClassNameA" _
(ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal nMaxCount As Long) As Long
#End If

#If VBA7 Then
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetCurrentThreadId Lib "kernel32" () As Long
#Else
Private Declare Function GetCurrentThreadId Lib "kernel32" () As Long
#End If


'~~> Constants to be used in our API functions
Private Const EM_SETPASSWORDCHAR = &HCC
Private Const WH_CBT = 5
Private Const HCBT_ACTIVATE = 5
Private Const HC_ACTION = 0

Private hHook As Long

Public Function NewProc(ByVal lngCode As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, _
ByVal lParam As Long) As Long
    Dim RetVal
    Dim strClassName As String, lngBuffer As Long

    If lngCode < HC_ACTION Then
        NewProc = CallNextHookEx(hHook, lngCode, wParam, lParam)
        Exit Function
    End If

    strClassName = String$(256, " ")
    lngBuffer = 255

    If lngCode = HCBT_ACTIVATE Then
        RetVal = GetClassName(wParam, strClassName, lngBuffer)
        '~~> Class name of the Inputbox
        If Left$(strClassName, RetVal) = "#32770" Then
            '~~> This changes the edit control so that it display the password character *.
            '~~> You can change the Asc("*") as you please.
            SendDlgItemMessage wParam, &H1324, EM_SETPASSWORDCHAR, Asc("*"), &H0
        End If
    End If

    '~~> This line will ensure that any other hooks that may be in place are
    '~~> called correctly.
    CallNextHookEx hHook, lngCode, wParam, lParam

End Function

Public Function InputBoxDK(Prompt, Optional Title, Optional Default, Optional XPos, _
Optional YPos, Optional HelpFile, Optional Context) As String
    Dim lngModHwnd As Long, lngThreadID As Long
    lngThreadID = GetCurrentThreadId
    lngModHwnd = GetModuleHandle(vbNullString)
    hHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CBT, AddressOf NewProc, lngModHwnd, lngThreadID)
    InputBoxDK = InputBox(Prompt, Title, Default, XPos, YPos, HelpFile, Context)
    UnhookWindowsHookEx hHook
End Function

Sub auto_open()
strUser = InputBox("Please Enter Your User ID.")
strPwd = InputBoxDK("Please Enter Your Password.")
End Sub
```

Comment: You seems to have some pointers declared as Long in your VB7 declarations. They should probably be LongPtr. I Have not checked all declarations, but for example CallNextHookEx  should be `Declare PtrSafe Function CallNextHookEx Lib "user32" Alias "CallNextHookEx" (ByVal hHook As LongPtr, ByVal ncode As Long, ByVal wParam As LongPtr, lParam As Any) As LongPtr`

Comment: Some tools can help you do the translations (like https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/dennis/windowsapiviewer.htm for example)

Comment: Is it possible that you've gone from 32bit Excel to 64bit, and that is screwing up things?

Comment: I couldn't get it to work with "longptr" but I just did a find and replace with "long" for "longlong" and it worked.  Thanks for pointing that out!  I did switch from 32 bit system to 64 bit system as well.

Comment: @AlmostThere I just verified this on my own system as well. Suggest you post the fixed code as an answer... :)